# How to convert to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How to convert the following query into linq

```
SELECT
    a.ProductId,
    a.Name,
    a.Description,
    b.Quoteid,
    b.Productid,
    b.Quantity,
    b.OriginalPrice
FROM
    Products        AS a
    LEFT JOIN
    QuoteDtails AS b
    ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId
    AND b.QuoteId = 200;
```

Don't know where to add the AND condition.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `linq` if you want to write `LEFT JOIN` of linq, you need to add

> into [temp collection] from [Left join talbe collection] in [temp collection].DefaultIfEmpty()

after Linq `join`

look like this.

```
from ss in Products
join aa in QuoteDtails
on ss.ProductId equals aa.ProductId into temp
from ds in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where ds.QuoteId = 200
select new 
{ 
    ProductId_P = ss.ProductId,
    Name = ss.Name,
    Description = ss.Description,
    Quoteid = ds.Quoteid,
    Productid_Q = ds.Productid,
    Quantity = ds.Quantity,
    OriginalPrice = ds.OriginalPrice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add AND condition in your LINQ query like this :

```
var res = from p in products
                  join q in quoteDtails on new { Criteria1 = p.ProductID, Criteria2 = 200 } equals new { Criteria1 = q.Productid, Criteria2 = q.Quoteid }
                  select new
                  {
                      ProductId_P = p.ProductID,
                      Name = p.Name,
                      Description = p.Description,
                      Quoteid = q.Quoteid,
                      Productid_Q = q.Productid,
                      Quantity = q.Quantity,
                      OriginalPrice = q.OriginalPrice
                  };
```